# Interact with Rviz, send multiple goals to path planner

Tags: navigation, rviz, interactive-markers, move-base, pathplanning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I want to send  multiple goals to path planner (move_base) using Rviz. I mean, normally the 2D Nav Goal button is used to send an unique goal to the planner. My question is if is possible to concatenate goals clicking in different points on the map.

Is there any Rviz functionality or is necessary to install a plugin or create something ad-hoc "home-made"?

Thank you very much in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220062/interact-with-rviz,-send-multiple-goals-to-path-planner/) by [Jose Luis](https://answers.ros.org/users/3057/jose-luis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 375 on 2015-10-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally, I have used a combination of two packages that are provided by ROS.
On one hand I have used a RViz plugin example for creating a new plugin on Rviz interface. The example that I took is *plant_flag_tool* in *rviz_plugin_tutorials* package.
Once I have a button in Rviz menu, I have created a custom interactive marker which is capable of move in XY plane and rotate in Z. By this way is possible to send a position and orientation to the path planner.
Each time that the user presses the button plugin on Rviz menu a new custom marker (new goal) is created.

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis](https://answers.ros.org/users/3057/jose-luis/) with karma: 375 on 2015-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1